# How does a using-declaration reduce the names available for lookup without ADL?

Tags: c++, namespaces, argument-dependent-lookup, name-lookup

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class X {};

namespace N
{

std::string to_string(X)
{
    return "foo";
}

void foo()
{
    //using std::to_string; // will break the build if uncommented...
    //using N::to_string;   // ...unless this is uncommented as well
    std::cout << to_string(X()) << std::endl;
}

}

int main()
{
    N::foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Either I have stumbled upon one of the many C++ arcana I do not master, or I am missing something obvious here.

How can `using std::to_string` apparently reduce the set of names available during unqualified lookup to only those reachable via ADL? While I can guess the problem might be that `to_string(X)` is declared in a different namespace than `X`, I cannot help but notice that, without `using std::to_string`, `N::to_string(X)` is simply available to `N::foo()` by using the "normal", intuitive lookup rules I am accustomed to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not specific to a using-declaration, but follows normal scoping rules. When you introduce a name into the function, that hides equally named things from outer scopes.

You could just as well have an `int  to_string;` local variable in `foo`. That would also hide `N::to_string`.

Comment: I notice, however, that the analogy with declaring `int to_string` does not *always* hold: in fact, `using std::to_string` does not hide a `to_string(X)` function declared in `X`'s namespace to be found from ADL, whereas `int to_string` will cause a compiler error. The analogy holds if I declare a `std::string to_string(int)`, for example, within `foo()`.

Comment: Yes, that's a different case. ADL will make the compiler consider a function from the parameter's associated namespace(s), even if it wouldn't be seen otherwise. But that's not the case for the code in the question, as `X` is outside of the namespace.